# A exceção NÃO confirma a regra. Por que razão se afirma o contrário?

Tags: significado, expressões, origem-histórica

Naturalmente, a exceção invalida a regra. Se a exceção confirmasse a regra teríamos que aceitar como verdadeiras as regras seguintes.

> Os mamíferos não voam. Os morcegos confirmam esta regra.
>
> O espanhol é a língua oficial nas capitais nacionais americanas a sul do equador. Brasília confirma esta regra.

Pode talvez argumentar-se que a regra não tem que ser absoluta, que pode ser tendencial. Vejamos uma exemplo mais próximo dos usos reais. Pedro afirma que é muito pontual, e Rita diz-lhe que ainda na terça-feira ele chegou meia hora atrasado. E ele naturalmente responde "isso é a exceção que confirma a regra." Ele poderia argumentar que a regra é tendencial, que ele é quase sempre pontual, e portanto o atraso na terça feira não invalida a regra da sua pontualidade. Nós podemos aceitar isto. Mas se não invalida, também não confirma. Nós, depois de sabermos que o Pedro chegou atrasado na terça feira, não vamos dizer "sim sim, claro, este atraso confirma que o Pedro é pontual."

Então a pergunta é **Qual é a origem da expressão *a exceção confirma a regra*?** E **com que significado é a expressão usada atualmente?** Pois já vimos que o significado literal é falso.

Entretanto encontrei a mesma discussão no SE.ELU: [**the exception that proves the rule**.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14193/what-is-the-exception-that-proves-the-rule)

Comment: Sempre imaginei que gradualmente a ideia de *uma exceção não invalida a regra* tivesse se corrompido para *uma exceção confirma a regra*, quando usada com freqüência sem pensar na lógica.


Como visto aqui nas outras respostas, existem maneiras melhores de explicar a expressão (*se existe uma exceção, é porque existe uma regra à qual essa exceção se aplica*), mas não duvidaria se algumas (muitas?) pessoas realmente entendessem que uma exceção reforça a regra e usassem isso como argumento (e por isso essa expressão sempre me irritava).

Comment: @marcus Aleluia, alguém que me compreende!

Comment: Na base do *achismo* parece-me que a exceção confirma a regra porque se é exceção que o Pedro tenha chegado atrasado, então quer dizer que ele por regra chega a horas.

Comment: Aí é que está o busílis. Como é que sabes que é exceção? Uma possibilidade é ele trabalhar contigo e tu sabe que até esse dia ele chegou sempre pontualmente. Mas então se ele um dia chegar atrasado, isso não vai confirmar nada.

Answer (score 16):

O teu erro é pensares que a expressão "a exceção confirma a regra" é alguma regra de lógica proposicional.

O que a expressão realmente significa é que a presença de uma exceção sugere a existência de uma regra.

Traduzindo da Wikipedia inglesa para a [expressão corresponde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule):

> A frase provém de um princípio legal da República Romana: *exceptio probat regulam in casibus non exceptis* ("a exceção confirma a regra nos casos não  excecionados"), um conceito proposto inicialmente por Cícero [...].
>   Isto significa que declarar uma exceção implica a existência de uma regra da qual ela é exceção.
>   A segunda parte da expressão de Cícero, "in casibus non exceptis" ("nos casos não excecionados" é quase sempre omitida dos usos modernos [...], o que pode contribuir para a frequente confusão e uso incorreto da expressão.
>   Fowler dá o seguinte exemplo do significado original:
>   Hoje é concedida licença especial para recolher aos quartéis até às 23h; "a exceção comprova a regra" significa que esta autorição especial implica a existência de uma regra que requer que os homens, tirando casos excecionais, tenham de recolher mais cedo.

Estritamente falando, esta conclusão não se segue (afinal de contas, que os homens tenham de recolher em dado dia a dada hora não nos diz nada sobre os outros dias). Mas porque ninguém havia de dar uma autorização especial por motivo nenhum, podemos inferir que, com alta probabilidade, existe uma regra por trás da exceção.

Comment: Essa parece ser a origem da expressão. Da declaração de uma exceção podemos com bastante segurança inferir, em certos contextos, até mesmo o próprio conteúdo da regra. Um restaurante com o aviso "fechamos à segunda feira para descanso do pessoal" quase certamente abre de terça a domingo.

Comment: Mas eu nunca ouvi ninguém hoje em dia dizer _a exceção confirma a regra_ com esse sentido. Ouve-se o que o mesmo artigo da Wikipedia intitula [disparate grave ou brincallhão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule#Jocular_nonsense) ou, com boa vontade, [retórica vaga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule#Loose_rhetorical_sense), que são casos em que **a exceção não confirma a regra.**  Portanto, tu entras a matar com o _meu erro_, mas não há erro nenhum.

Comment: Sua resposta é excepcional e confirma a minha :)

Comment: @Jacinto A tua pergunta pede explicitamente a origem da expressão. Sendo uma frase feita que "soa a verdade", depois as pessoas (mesmo que não saibam o seu significado original) hão-de pegar nela e usá-la de forma que não faz qualquer sentido (de forma jocosa ou para mostrar indiferença, por exemplo como resposta perante uma facto que contradiz uma regra que o locutor defende). Mas isso já tu capturaste na pergunta.

Comment: Capturei isso na pergunta, e mesmo assim acusas-me logo a abrir de erro. Fogo!

Answer (score 8):

Não sei quando nem como a expressão surgiu, mas nunca a considerei estranha. Você chegou bem perto do meu entendimento na segunda parte da pergunta, com aquele exemplo do Pedro atrasado.

O que confirma a regra é o fato de a exceção ser uma exceção. Se não fosse, a regra não seria regra (ou seria outra). O atraso de Pedro só é uma exceção porque ele é notoriamente pontual. Se não fosse, esse atraso nada teria de excepcional. Esse atraso só chama a atenção porque a regra é Pedro chegar no horário combinado. Por isso o atraso é a exceção que confirma a regra.

O que confirma a regra não é a exceção em si, mas o fato de ela existir. Porque, como todos sabemos, *toda regra tem uma exceção* ;)

Comment: Gostei. _Se_ nós soubermos que o atraso é excecional, então sabemos que regra geral o Pedro é pontual. Mas... mas... mas tenho que ir tomar o pequeno almoço e pensar no assunto. _Toda a regra tem uma exceção_ é uma regra bem interessante: acho que se contradiz a si mesma. Precisamos de um SE.Logic.

Comment: Também gostei! De fato, para que haja uma exceção, é necessário haver uma regra. Entretanto acredito que a contradição surja quando usamos essa máxima com assuntos que são facilmente verificáveis. O exemplo das capitais sul-americanas não é exatamente um caso em que usaríamos essa máxima. Entretanto, a pontualidade de Pedro, apesar de notória, não é facilmente verificável tampouco garante-se que será mantida no futuro. Sendo assim, as regras que se comprovam pelas exceções são inerentes aos assuntos que não possuem regras, mas para os quais tentamos encontrar um padrão.

Comment: @Bell Não queres desenvolver numa resposta a tua ideia de "as regras que se comprovam por exceções são inerentes ..."? Com um exemplo? Exemplos são sempre o melhor.

Comment: @Bell Continuando a partir do mas... mas... mas... **Confirmar** = _tornar ou tornar-se mais firme, certo ou credível._ -- DACL. Suponhamos que o Pedro chegou 99 vezes pontualmente e uma vez atrasado, e nós sabemos isso. Então sabemos que o atraso é excecional, o que implica que a regra é a pontualidade (tendencial). Mas nós só sabemos que o atraso é excecional porque sabemos das 99 chegadas pontuais. Estas é que nos dão confiança na regra. O atraso não vem tornar a pontualidade do Pedro mais credível (confirmar). Quando muito, vem reduzir a nossa confiança na pontualidade do Pedro.

Comment: @Bell Bfavaretto avança com a ideia que a exceção chama a atenção para a regra. Acho que isto pode ser verdade nalguns casos. Não tou convencido que seja no caso do Pedro. Mas tenho um exemplo real. Há uns bons anos, a água da torneira no Algarve, apesar de perfeitamente potável, tinha um gosto horrível. E eu quando a bebia, por engano, lembrava-me que a água da torneira em Portugal é regra geral razoavelmente boa. Uma exceção pode chamar a atenção para uma regra da qual, por tanto a tomamos por adquirida, nós nos esquecemos.

Comment: Mas chamar a atenção não é a mesma coisa que confirmar, nem me parece que esta interpretação se aplique na maior parte dos uso reais da máxima. É preciso mais investigação.

Comment: Excelente explicação.

Comment: > "*Toda a regra tem uma exceção* é uma regra bem interessante: acho que se contradiz a si mesma", @Jacinto sim, contradiz, é um paradoxo verdadeiro (digo por ênfase, porque há uma série de situações chamadas de paradoxos que, a rigor, são *paradoxos aparentes*) do tipo que comumente aparece quando não se toma o cuidado de separar a linguagem da metalinguagem.

Answer (score 0):

O Artefacto está intrinsecamente correto...

Definição de Provérbio:

> s.m. Frase, ou ditado curto de origem popular, que resume um conceito
>   moral, uma norma social: "só percebemos o valor da água depois que a
>   fonte seca".  Cristianismo. Segundo os textos bíblicos, frase que
>   possui o intuito de educar ou aconselhar; pensamento.  s.m.pl.
>   Provérbios. Refere-se ao livro bíblico, Livro dos Provérbios, do
>   Antigo Testamento, cujos textos têm o propósito de educar ou
>   aconselhar.  (Etm. do latim: proverbium.ii)

Isto não é nem Filosofia nem Matemática, é cultura, baseada em Costumes,
ou seja, é mais complexo que puras noções aritméticas e filosóficas.
Não vou referir as origens porque já foi referida uma das mais apoiadas(e comprovadas).

Vamos por fases:
Pense só assim...

Regra = NORMA / Exemplo(em sentido mais Lato)

Em Regra= Geralmente, na generalidade.

Excepção = Desvio ou Restrição da regra geral / Privilégio,prerrogativa(sentido mais lato)

à excepção de= Sem incluir no número; excepto.

Vamos ser extremos para perceber que a regra e a excepção estão intimamente ligadas:
Sem Vida existe morte? então e tinha lógica existir a definição de começo sem haver um fim? ou vice-versa?
A excepção só confirma a regra porque é uma excepção em si... Se a regra é você voar... A excepção seria você andar... Todos voam... Excepto você...

Quer pensar? então pense nisto:
1- Uma coisa Impossível...pode deixar de ser?Quando?
2- Regra é imutável?o que hoje parece certo amanha será?

Ps:
    1- Quando acontece!
    2- A Terra no tempo de Platão era quadrada(era regra) e hoje?

Desculpem qualquer erro gramatical e qualquer falta de pontuação.

Cumprimentos para todos!